# How do find letters in string and show complete word

Tags: php

How can I find with letters a word in a string?

Example (No code):

> String -> Hello you live in Oklahoma.city its cool
>
> Find -> .city
>
> Show -> Oklahoma.city

I can check if exists like this:

```
$string = "Carlos.name its a name, Miami.city its a city, 15.number its a number";

if (stripos($string, '.city') !== false) {
echo "Exists";
}
```

But i need show **Miami.city** ..

Thanks so much

Comment: Find the position of `".city"` then read backwards until you find a space. There's your word.

Answer (score 0):

Try with regular expressions. This could be made with a positive lookahead:

```
if (preg_match('[(?<city>\w+)(?=\.city)]', $string, $matches)) {
    echo $matches['city'];
}
```

The expression explained in detail does something like this:

1. Create a named group `city` which matches all word characters (`\w`)
2. Look ahead and only match the named group if you find the string `.city`

Comment: thanks you I tested but it doesn't work
Warning: preg_match(): Unknown modifier '(' in D:\xampp\htdocs\test.php on line 7

Comment: Sorry, forgot the deliminators. Updated my example. But I also noticed, that my example does not match exactly what you are trying to match. It will return just `Miami` not `Miami.city`.

Answer (score 0):

Another regex.  Just look for NOT spaces and followed by `.city`:

```
if(preg_match('/[^ ]+\.city/', $string, $match)) {
    echo $match[0];
}
```